# error C2259: cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, templates, observer-pattern

i am trying to understand observer pattern using C++.
I am basically trying to write a simple program using template to understand it,i must confess that i am not that verse with template programming and because of it i am not able to fix this compile error.It would be great if someone can please point out what i am doing wrong

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<list>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class IEventListener
{
public:
  virtual ~IEventListener() {}
  virtual void onEvent(T eventData) = 0;
};

template <class T>
class EventGenerator
{
public:
  EventGenerator(){}
  virtual ~EventGenerator() {}
  void addListener(IEventListener<T> l)
  {
    listeners.push_back(l);
  }

  void trigger(T eventData)
  {
    for (auto it = listeners.begin(); it != listeners.end(); ++it)
    {
      (*it).onEvent(eventData);
    }
  }
private:
  std::list<IEventListener<T>> listeners;
};

class IntListener : public IEventListener<int>
{
public:
  //event callback
  virtual void onEvent(int eventData)
  {
    std::cout << "int" <<eventData<< std::endl;
  }
};

class ActualIntEventGenerator : public EventGenerator<int>    
{
public:
  void firstMethod()
  {
    int a = 10;
    trigger(a);
  }
};

void main()
{
  IntListener i;
  ActualIntEventGenerator intGenerator;
  intGenerator.addListener(i);
  Sleep(5000);
}
```

The error which i am getting is

```
error C2259: 'IEventListener<int>' : 
cannot instantiate abstract class due to following members:
void IEventListener<int>::onEvent(T)' : is abstract with [T=int]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Search the web for the error message. Reduce the code to the smallest amount of code (a single class + `main()` should suffice). Avoid being dissed for using `conio.h` and `windows.h` and being downvoted for not doing that all before posting here.

Comment: `intGenerator.addListener(i);` tries to convert `IntListener` to abstract class `IEventListener`. You perhaps want

    `std::list< shared_ptr< IEventListener<T> > > listeners;`

or something similar to avoid object slicing. And then you won't see this error any more.

Comment: i dont think that is the issue even when i comment out `intGenerator.addListener(i);` i get the same error.The error only goes away if i get rid of body of class ActualIntEventGenerator